# Get Category IDs for Product via Service Contract / API

Tags: magento2, api, magento-2.0, category-products, service-contract

In Magento 2, is there a way to get the assigned category ids for a given product, via Service Contracts?

The `CategoryLinkManagementInterface` API interface only has one method that returns the assigned products for a given category ID, but I need it the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found such method from the service contracts.

The only way I can see this working via a service contract is by using `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` to get the product first (via `get` or `getById` ) and then call `getCategoryIds` on that product.

Comment: Unfortunately, `getCategoryIds` is also not part of `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`, so I'll end up with a leaking abstraction. But it looks like this is unavoidable currently.

Comment: @fschmengler may be time for a PR ;)

Comment: In 2.1 an interface has been added that seems to be made for this, but unfortunately there is no implementation yet: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/CategoryProductSearchResultInterface.php